# cmake cant generate sfml build files

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, terminal, sfml, vorbis

I'm trying to generate build files for sfml on linux ubuntu using cmake, but the dependencies were not installed. I installed most with not issues, but one still persists. I got the following error message in the cmake gui:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
Could NOT find VORBIS (missing: VORBIS_LIBRARIES VORBIS_INCLUDE_DIR
OGG_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/Modules/FindVORBIS.cmake:25 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
cmake/Macros.cmake:384 (find_package)
src/SFML/Audio/CMakeLists.txt:70 (sfml_find_package)
```

I tried installing VORBIS librabry using the terminal as so:

```
sudo apt-get install -y vorbis-tools
```

But it's already the newest version. Shouldnt CMake find the dependency and configure properly? I couldnt find much help using Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFML [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/43b2e9dc125954a40af8a4dc135a6841b4adabb8/cmake/Modules/FindVORBIS.cmake#L10-L11) searches for the following files:

```
find_path(OGG_INCLUDE_DIR ogg/ogg.h)
find_path(VORBIS_INCLUDE_DIR vorbis/vorbisfile.h)
```

packages.ubuntu.com says that these files are in the `libogg-dev` and `libvorbis-dev` packages, respectively.